# how do I add to a number value in html through javascript

Tags: javascript, button, addition

I tried

```
HTML:
<br> <span id="myspan">0</span>
Javascript:
button.addEventListener("click"), function() { document.getElementById("myspan").textContent=("+-1"); };
```

but it didn't seem to be working and nothing seemed to cover this. I was trying to make a click counter for fun and the button click listener, I don't know if it worked.

```
Javascript:
button.addEventListener("click"), function() { document.getElementById("myspan").textContent=("+-1"); };
```

Comment: You're setting the text to the literal string `+-1`. If you want to perform arithmetic on the text, you should convert the text to a number, perform arithmetic on the number, and assign it back to the text.

Comment: Why did you post the same JS twice?

Comment: `button` isn't defined anywhere, and you have a typo when calling `addEventListener` (you close the parentheses before the second argument to that function).  Now is a good time to start looking at your browser's development tools, in which the console is showing you an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `addEventListener` isn't correct.

`button.addEventListener("click"), function() {` should actually be `button.addEventListener("click", function() {})` since the function needs to be within the parentheses.`

```
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const span = document.getElementById("myspan");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {  
  let val = parseInt(span.innerText || '') || 0;
  val++;
  span.innerText= val;
});
```

https://codepen.io/dirtyd77/pen/KKErYRy